# ajax callback method but unsuccessful return

Tags: php, html, ajax, callback

Problem: i can pass value to the ajax method and successfully implement Select SQL (results seen in Network), but it never return back any result  (My result is alert ("successful).  What is the problem of it?

HTML:

```
function selectupdate_Server(id)
    {
        var ID= id;
        console.log(ID);   --->Successfully logged 
        $.ajax({
            url: "abc.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"ID": ID},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert ('Success');   ------>Failed to alert

            }
        });

    }
```

PHP:

```
   $serverName = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
   $password = "root";
  $dbName = "noticeboard";
  $tbName1 = "notice";
   $conn = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $dbName);

  checkStaffLogin();

function checkStaffLogin()
{
global $conn, $tbName1;
if ($conn->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Fail to connect MYSQL database : " . $conn->connect_errno;
}
else {
     $ID= $_POST["ID"];

    $sql = "SELECT *
                     FROM $tbName1 where ID= '$ID'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if($result)
 { 
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
    {
        $table_data[]=           array("Name"=>$row['Name'],"Password"=>$row['Password']);
    }

        echo json_encode($table_data);
}
```

Comment: add `exit;`  at the end in your php function

Comment: Your PHP code might contain errors. Check browser console or show us the entire PHP code

Comment: Undefined index: ID    &  Undefined variable: table_data

Comment: but i have check ID before   "console.log(ID)"

Comment: @soul299 how is the ID named in the database?

Comment: you try this in ajax script success `alert (JSON.stringify(data));`.here json format result alert

Comment: try changing to this `data: {ID: ID},`

Comment: try to check your `$tbName1` variable, as your code seems fine to me, maybe error in other location inside your PHP code?

Comment: $tbName1 is okay    becuase i can see the select result from Network

Comment: where can you see the result from Network?

Comment: Undefined index: ID   &&  Undefined variable: table_data &&mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: what is the name of your table and the fields in it?

Comment: is your id a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 $table_data=[];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbName1." where ID = ".$ID;
```

note: Use preperd statements
and append this header to your php `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

to loop the results use

```
success: function (data) {
               $.each(data,function(i,v){
                     console.log(v.Name)
               });
            }
```

note data should look like this:

```
data: {ID: ID},
```

Comment: SW registered   undefined

Comment: do you have a variable named SW?

Comment: i dont have SW variable

Comment: post all your php code for this ajax and the table structure

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php 
    $ID= $_POST["ID"];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbName1."where ID=".$ID;

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
        {
            $table_data[]=           array("Name"=>$row['Name'],"Password"=>$row['Password']);
        }

            echo json_encode($table_data);
?>
```

try this

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in 
&&&&&&
  Undefined variable: table_data in

Answer (score 0):

In JS check your syntax for data by removing those "ID". Try the following

```
function selectupdate_Server(id)
    {
        var ID= id;
         $.ajax({
            url: "abc.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {ID: ID},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert ('Success');  

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What is the different between "ID" and ID  but before i use "" , it works too

Answer (score 0):

You Try this Javascript function

```
function selectupdate_Server(id)
{
    var ID= id;
    console.log(ID);   --->Successfully logged 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {ID: ID},
         url: "abc.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resultss){
            try{
             alert ('Success'); 
            }catch(e)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(e)+"Catch error");//any Error in Your php file display alert.where,what error
            }

        },
        error: function(e){

         alert(JSON.stringify(e)+"error");//any Error in Your php file display alert.where,what error

        }
        });

}
```

this script where error in your php file alert that line no and file name you check and correction

and You Php code like this

```
 checkStaffLogin();
 function checkStaffLogin()
 {
  $serverName = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbName = "noticeboard";
  $tbName1 = "notice";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $username, $password, $dbName);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
else {
  $ID= $_POST["ID"];
  $table_data=array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbName1 where ID= '$ID'";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
  if($result)
  { 
  while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
  {
    $table_data[]= array("Name"=>$row['Name'],"Password"=>$row['Password']);
  }

    echo json_encode($table_data);
  }
 }
 }
```

You try this like this

Comment: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\IT\\Admin_Notice_SelectUpdate.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\IT\\Admin_Notice_SelectUpdate.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />\n[]","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}error

Comment: you show full php code with database connection . i think error in you db coonection

Comment: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\IT\\Admin_Notice_SelectUpdate.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}error

Comment: line 27 :     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)  or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: you have teamviewer ?

Comment: ok send me teamviewer user id and pwd to vadiveljobs@gmail.com